# What is value of $\prod_{x\geq 2} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\;?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For $x \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ what is:

$$
\prod_{x\geq 2} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\;?
$$

Numerically it seems to be approximately $3.676$.

Comment: Do you mean $p^2-1$ in the denominator ? Moreover, what is $p$ ? Any number, or prime number ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you. Typos fixed.

Comment: What is the upper bound of $p$?

Comment: @NoChance It's an infinite product.

Comment: Maple says it's $(\sinh \pi)/\pi.$  I have no idea how.

Comment: Maybe taking logarithm may help.

Comment: This may be remotely related: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html

Comment: Maybe rewriting it as follows and using Taylor series for the logarithm expression might help:

$$\exp\ln\prod_{x\ge2}\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}=\exp\sum_{x\ge2}\ln\left(1+\dfrac{2}{x^2-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html).

What is amazing is that the partial products
$$P_n=\prod_{x=2}^n \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}=\frac{\sinh (\pi )}\pi\, \frac{ \Gamma (n+1-i) \,\Gamma (n+1+i)}{  \Gamma (n)\, \Gamma (n+2)}$$ Using Stirling approximation of the gamma function, the asymptotics
$$P_n=\frac{\sinh (\pi )}\pi\,\left(1-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)\right)$$

Comment: It would be great if you could add an explanation for the first line of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer:

$$\prod_{x\geq2} \frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} = 
\prod_{x\geq2} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$

Then Maple says that both the numerator and denominator converge.  It gives

$$\prod_{x\geq2} 1-\frac{1}{x^2}  = \frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$\prod_{x\geq2} 1+\frac{1}{x^2}  = \frac{\sinh \pi}{2\pi}.$$

So your product is apparently equal to $(\sinh \pi)/\pi.$

Comment: This is discussed in [Borwein's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=10BZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6).